# How to capture raw frame of /dev/video0 through v4l2

Tags: c, v4l2

Recently, I'm trying to capture video's raw data. On my desktop, `video0` is webcam.

If I type:

```
vlc v4l2:///dev/video0
```

my webcam will open, and my face will show up in vlc player.

I tried to use sample code [here](https://gist.github.com/maxlapshin/1253534) and it is assumed be correct. When I run this user application, error will show up and tell me device or resource is busy because I query buffer which is writing. My question is how to capture properly?

Complete error message is:

```
VIDIOC_REQBUFS error 16, Device or resource busy\n
```

Comment: Can you copy here the exact error you see?

Comment: Edited, I think it is reasonable that can't request device which is busy ( webcam is writing now ). There is lot of v4l2 capture example code on internet, but they don't show how they execute this code.

Comment: Oh you're trying to run it while vlc is capturing video? I don't think that will work. What happens when you run it without vlc running?

Comment: If not, capture.c will generate lot of raw data files which are all empty. It is reasonable again, cuz video0 doesn't have any image now.

Comment: How long did you run it for? It may take a few seconds for the webcam to activate after starting video capture resulting in the first N frames being black.

Comment: I generate around 1500 frame data which takes 30~50 seconds. Those file are all empty. ( My webcam signal have turned green )

Comment: I find the thing I did wrong. I miss type execute command. It should be ./app -o